# Input field - remove value when onClick events and restore the value if not set

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

In the input field I set a default value. The default value must be removed when click inside the field, but if the value insert is blank and the mouse cursor leave the field, must be restored the default value. The default value must be writing in the database.

For example:

Default value: 0

When I leave the input field and the value is blank,the default value is  restored .

```
<input type="text" onclick="if(this.value == 'value') { this.value = ''; }" value="value" />
```

How to restore the default value if any value is set to input after click?

Thanks

Comment: It's extremely hard to understand what you are asking for, would it be possible to review/rephrase this question (obvious typos like `filed` <-> `field` are very annoying for careful readers)?

Comment: I change filed in field. What's the difficult to understand my phrases? When leave the input field and the value is blank, restore the default value.

Comment: So, add a check for whether the value is “blank” to the if condition …

Comment: I read that if the input value differs from default, the default should be restored: *`value insert is different by default value`* -- a misunderstanding?

Comment: Try using html-Element-Events see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp.

For example "onmouseout" may be helpful.

Comment: @Wolf: Sorry, I have redefine my phrases to: _The default value must be removed when click inside the filed, but if the value insert is blank and the mouse cursor leave the field_ . Updated post.

Comment: @Tallerlei: I try the events, but if use the onmouseout, when mouse leave the field remove the value and not like this.

Comment: `onblur="if(this.value === ''){this.value='value'}"` try this.

Comment: modern day browsers do this with `placeholder`. Unless you are supporting a really old browser, there is ZERo reason to use JavaScript.

Comment: @epascarello: But, with _placeholder_ the value 0 (placeholder="0") is saved on database?

Comment: No, that would be the job of the server to set the default values when reading it. Seems like a step for the validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just attach `listener` to your input on the `focus` and `blur` events like bellow example ;

```js
var inputToCheck = document.getElementById("inputNum");
inputToCheck.initialValue = inputToCheck.value || '';

inputToCheck.addEventListener("focus",function(e) {
     this.value == this.initialValue ? this.value = "" : "";
});

inputToCheck.addEventListener("blur",function(e) {
     this.value == "" ? this.value = this.initialValue : "";
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputNum" value="0" />
```

Another with jQuery :

```js
var inputToCheck = $("#inputNum");
inputToCheck.data("initialValue", inputToCheck.val());

inputToCheck.on("focus",function(e) {
     this.value == $(this).data("initialValue") ? this.value = "" : "";
}).on("blur",function(e) {
     this.value == "" ? this.value = $(this).data("initialValue") : "";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inputNum" value="0" />
```

Comment: While that works with a hardcoded default (0), it would be nice if you could improve your answer to make it work with whatever `value=""` is predefined in the markup.

Comment: @Connum Yep I agree :),  fixed as you said .

Comment: erm... the edit is actually not what I suggested. Now you just removed the value from the markup. What I suggested was saving the value from the markup temprarily, then checking against it (instead of a hardcoded 0).

Comment: @bRIMOs: Thanks for your solution. I use the javascript solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Frankie Welcome ;)

Comment: Just made the edit. Now you can have whatever value attribute you like in the markup instead of hard-coded.

Comment: @Connum great , thnks for improvement .

Answer (score 0):

Does using placeholder attribute serve your requirement
?

This will show default value if the field is left blank., But won't send it to server when form is submitted with field value is blank.If you want to save the default value when user submits the form with blank input, write an obsubmit handler for the form that sets the value to default, or implement it in the server side to save default value in db if value is blank.

Comment: Thanks but placeholder value 0 (placeholder="0") not saved on database

Comment: For that add a function for submit of the form and set the value of the field to default if the value is blank.